# Estoy trabajando con 3 bases, debo crear una nueva variable

Tags: r, rstudio

Uní las 3 bases y creé una sola llamada *data*. Ahora me piden crear una nueva variable llamada *ecivil* que diferencie el estado civil de todos los individuos. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

```
load("C:/Users/DELL/Downloads/solteros.Rdata")
View(solteros)

 casados <- read_excel("C:/Users/DELL/Downloads/casados.xlsx")
View(casados)

divorcio <- read.csv("C:/Users/DELL/Downloads/divorcio.txt")
 View(divorcio)

data<-rbind(solteros,casados,divorcio)
```

Ese es mi avance de cómo uní las 3 bases.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te puedo sugerir, es que agregues esta columna a cada base datos antes de hacer el `rbind`, por ejemplo:

```
solteros$ecivil <- "S"
casados$ecivil <- "C"
divorcio$ecivil <- "D"

data<-rbind(solteros,casados,divorcio)
```

La codificación puede ser otra, lo importante es hacerlo antes del `rbind`